# How to verify that feature branch doesn't contain any merge commits and is up to date?

Tags: bash, git, shell, github, circleci

I'm using GitHub with CircleCI and would like to verify that all pull request that come to my master branch are from a feature branch that contains no merge commits that do not exists in master, and also that the feature branch was rebased on top of the latest master.

This means that I always want the history to look like this:

```
*   1924562 Merge pull request #2 from feature-2
|\
| * 02ebbde Commit 6
| * 514752d Commit 5
| * 204d48f Commit 4
| * a1d16da Commit 3
|/
*   d03cd1e Merge pull request #1 from feature-1
|\
| * d6fe4ad Commit 2
| * 7aa415c Commit 1
|/
*   6ac1979 Initial commit
```

and not for example this:

```
*   1924562 Merge pull request #2 from feature-2
|\
| *   1abfe7f Merge branch 'extra-branch-1' into feature-2
| |\
| * | 02ebbde Commit 6
| * | 514752d Commit 5
| | * 204d48f Commit 4
| |/
| * a1d16da Commit 3
|/
*   d03cd1e Merge pull request #1 from feature-1
|\
| * d6fe4ad Commit 2
| * 7aa415c Commit 1
|/
*   6ac1979 Initial commit
```

and not like this:

```
*   1924562 Merge pull request #2 from feature-2
|\
| * 02ebbde Commit 6
| * 514752d Commit 5
| * 204d48f Commit 4
| * a1d16da Commit 3
* | d03cd1e Merge pull request #1 from feature-1
|\|
| * d6fe4ad Commit 2
| * 7aa415c Commit 1
|/
*   6ac1979 Initial commit
```

I'm thinking that I could achieve this by running a shell script as part of my CircleCI pipeline, which would assert that every commit from the feature branch is ok.

The problem is that I'm not exactly sure how I'd implement such script. I guess a starting point would be to check every commit that only exists in the feature branch and verify that they have only 1 parent commit:

```
[ $(git show --no-patch --format="%P" | wc -w) -eq 1 ] || exit 1
```

but I'm not sure how to catch the second error case shown where the feature branch doesn't start from the latest marge commit of master. (I'm thinking that `git merge-base` could probably be used for that part.) But it also feels like that this is something that must've been solved already so I don't know if reinventing the wheel by starting from scratch makes much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can :

1. check that `master` is an ancestor of `branch` :

```
if ! git merge-base --is-ancestor master $branch; then
   echo "please rebase $branch on top of master"
   exit 1
fi
```

2. use `git rev-list --merges` or `git log --merges` to check if there are no merges on `branch` :

```
cnt=$(git rev-list --count --merges master..$branch)

if [ "$cnt" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "there are merge commits on $branch"
    exit 2
fi
```

`1.` will make sure the latest `master` is part of target branch's history, `2.` will make sure this history only consists of a straight line of commits on top of `master`.